# Including other languages into $content. ="";

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get this

```
<style type="text/css">
  .hidden {
  display: none;
  }
</style>
<form>
      <input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('hidden').style.display = 'block';" />
</form>
<img id="hidden" class="hidden" src="http://mmgtv.org/limelight/wp-content/themes/technetiumastic/images/loader.gif" />
```

into this

```
$content .= 'I AM TRYING TO PUT THE CODE INTO HERE';
```

what can I do?

Comment: You want to put HTML code into a string variable? What is the problem? If you have problems with quotes use escape sequences.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#example-71) syntax:

```
$content. = <<<EOD
<style type="text/css">
.hidden {
display: none;
}
</style>
<form>
<input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('hidden').style.display = 'block';" />
</form>
<img id="hidden" class="hidden" src="http://mmgtv.org/limelight/wp-content/themes/technetiumastic/images/loader.gif" />
EOD;
```

Comment: dude, why have you deleted part of my answer ? I think you are misusing edit rights! don't do this again :)

Comment: @Dmitry Sorry about it, I don't know how it happened (accidentally deleting a line??). I just wanted to fix your answer by adding an ending apostrophe and a semicolon to the end of the first line. I did not intend to do anything malicious, sorry. I am serious about not misusing my rights.

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = '<style type="text/css">
  .hidden {
  display: none;
  }
</style>
<form>
      <input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="document.getElementById(\'hidden\').style.display = \'block\';" />
</form>
<img id="hidden" class="hidden" src="http://mmgtv.org/limelight/wp-content/themes/technetiumastic/images/loader.gif" />';
```

but why?

Answer (score 0):

yes. Use **escape characters** for that:

```
$content .= '<style type="text/css">';
$content .=  '.hidden {';
$content .=  'display: none;';
$content .=  '}';
$content .= '</style>';
$content .= '<form>';

.....

$content .= ' <input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="document.getElementById(\'hidden\').style.display = \'block\';" />';
```

**see how backslashes are added to the last line of code.**

Comment: At that point you might as well just use a HEREDOC and not have to use escape chars as well. Repeated string concatenation is just painful to read through.

Comment: why would you push one solution over another? I'm familiar with HEREDOC. But honestly I prefer adding html code using CreateElement. That is an educational thread, where we share different ways of doing it. Let @Bryan decide which one to use.